# fastest way to drag columns in excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office

do you know how to drag  data in excel fastly? because I have +/-100K data, and I want to drag them and copy them. What is the fastest way to copy that data?

Comment: it would help if you can explain what you are trying to drag, is it a table, and do you wish to select all of it?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use `Ctrl-Shift-End` on the first cell in order to copy an entire table.

If you want to select a whole row or column of data only (and want it to stop at the last value), use `Ctrl-Shift` + arrow keys to quickly select or just `Ctrl` + arrow keys to quickly jump around through the data